# get_googlemap: I need to calculate the bounds of a map given center and zoom level

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I get the map using get_googlemap

```
location <- c(lon = -87.67946, lat = 41.86242)
map <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = location, zoom = 11), extent = "device")
```

Once I have a ggmap, I want to learn what are the exact boundaries of my map to further use it for creating a heatmap from data with coordinates.

Please, help me **calculate the bounds of a map given center and zoom level.**

I tried looking for answer in ?get_googlemap and ?ggmap documentations but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` member of the object `map` contains `lat` and `lon` columns that specify the bounds:

```r
library(ggmap)

location <- c(lon = -87.67946, lat = 41.86242)
map <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = location, zoom = 11), extent = "device")

range(map$data$lon)
#> [1] -87.89884 -87.45939

range(map$data$lat)
#> [1] 41.69831 42.02560
```

To demonstrate this is right, let's plot a red rectangle around our map using these numbers:

```r
map +
  annotate("rect", xmin = min(map$data$lon), xmax = max(map$data$lon),
           ymin = min(map$data$lat), ymax = max(map$data$lat), fill = NA,
           color = "red", linewidth = 3)
```

[image]

Or if you want to create a grid over the map,

```r
map + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(min(map$data$lat), max(map$data$lat), len = 10)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(min(map$data$lon), max(map$data$lon), len = 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for such a descriptive message!